# cross-domain drag and drop from an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, drag-and-drop, cross-domain

I am getting "SecurityError: The operation is insecure" in firefox when dragging a link from an iframe.

my situation is similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/ee7x1h4u/

the error occurs on this line in the ondrop() event when i try to drag and drop the title of the youtube video which is inside the iframe:

```
urldata = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
```

Is it even possible to make it work in my own server (meteorjs backend)?
thanks!

Comment: If it's just a link try sending the link data through the window messenger that can communicate between iframe and parent window (you would need code on both ends meaning iframe and parent for it to work though ) also it only supports basic objects nothing like elements

Comment: read up on *"same origin policy"* . Can only do things like that if you control code in both domains

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the server rather it is with client side javascript security. This is security built into all modern web browsers designed to protect users from websites suffering cross site scripting attacks. There is no way to override this safely, the only work around is to use a proxy script under your main domain so that both pages are under t b e samedomain so within the same security restriction space.

Comment: Anything like that would work as long as it exists under the same fully qualified domain name, so same scheme, same sub domain, same domain, same port, just different directory. If you are using the Apache web server you can even take a look at mod_proxy which will let you achieve the same thing but by using the same server. You can see more information on it at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html.

Comment: no, i'm using meteorjs as a fullstack solution. thanks, i might give it a try, but if this means i will have to "tunnel" the video content through the proxy, it may result it problems with the hosting provider too, so probably not worth it